# How to change Android Notification using Accessibility API

Tags: android, notifications

I am able to intercept all notifications using an Accessablity service.  This block is where the events are seen :

```
   @Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.d(tag, "Inside onAccessibilityEvent");
    if (event.getEventType() ==           AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED){
        SqlDb db = new SqlDb(this);
        NotificationObject no = new NotificationObject();
        no.setNoficationPackage(String.valueOf(event.getPackageName()));
        no.setNotificationText(String.valueOf(event.getText().toString()));
        no.setNotificationDTM(new Date());
        db.addNotification(no);
        Log.d(tag, "Saved event");
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to change the notification so it is not considered a missed call event.  Is this possible to do on OS 4.0+?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another application's notification is READ-ONLY.
So, code like "notification.a = b; "cause permission problem.

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
            //Do something, eg getting packagename
            final String packagename = String.valueOf(event.getPackageName());
            final String text = String.valueOf(event.getText());

            if(TARGET_PACKAGE.equals(packagename)){
                Notification n = (Notification) event.getParcelableData();
        }
}
```